# Symfony2 Querybuilder - Many to many relationship

Tags: symfony, doctrine, many-to-many, query-builder

I'm struggling a bit with the query builder. I have entities Category and Budget which have many-to-many relationship. User should be able to create new budgets with given categories. When creating new budget I want to check whether there is not already existing budget, that contains given categories.
To explain a bit better, let's say I have categories: Food, Travel, Electronics and already created budget for Travel and Food and then user wants to create another budget for Travel and Food, which he of course shouldn't.
I tried using IN but it only takes single value not an array:

```
$budgets = $this->createQueryBuilder('bud');
$budgets->where('bud.user = :user')
->andWhere($budgets->expr()->in('bud.tags', array(10, 11, 12)))
->setParameter('user', $budget->getUser())
->getQuery()->getResult();
```

Which of course throws an exception.

Answer (score 0):

A part of the answer would be :

```
// Example - $qb->expr()->in('u.id', array(1, 2, 3))
// Make sure that you do NOT use something similar to $qb->expr()->in('value', array('stringvalue')) as this will cause Doctrine to throw an Exception.
// Instead, use $qb->expr()->in('value', array('?1')) and bind your parameter to ?1 (see section above)
public function in($x, $y); // Returns Expr\Func instance
```

I see it [here](http://guidella.free.fr/General/symfony2QueryBuilder.html).

**EDIT**
There is an SQL statement which allow you to filter rows that only check all of given values.
It's `ALL` statement.

For [MySQL](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/all-subqueries.html)
For [SQL Server](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us//library/ms173270%28v=sql.100%29.aspx)
For [ORACLE](http://www.oracle-base.com/articles/misc/all-any-some-comparison-conditions-in-sql.php)

With Doctrine use (from [here](http://guidella.free.fr/General/symfony2QueryBuilder.html))

```
// Example - $qb->expr()->all($qb2->getDql())
public function all($subquery); // Returns Expr\Func instance
```

Where `$subquery` should be something like:

```
SELECT id_categorie FROM budget_categorie WHERE id_budget = '$idBudget'
```

Comment: Yes, but the problem with in function is, that the $x parameter can be only a single value (meaning that in will return all results that have  the same id as those in array in $y parameter) and I can't do in('bud.tags', array(1,2,3))

Comment: Problem is in 'bud.tags' not in the array, bud.tags is an array and it has to be single value

Comment: Sorry for my confusion. I'm searching for the good issue now... ;) Could you show the part of the database which store budget and budget_categories?

Comment: Thank you I'll take a look at the all statement and let you know where I got :), if I still won't be to solve it I'll update my question with db and entity classes